# tSql plot point in centre of grid cells

Tags: sql, grid, coordinates, spatial, centroid

Original question below:

'What is the best way to achieve the below in sql:

Take an area such as Chicago Illinois, place a grid over it of cells 50m x 50m and place a point in the centre of each grid cell. The coordinates of each point will be used to look at a table of lat/longs and calculate which of these points are within 200m of each point from the grid.'

To provide more detail to the above to make things a bit clearer. The greater aim is to:

Query a table of lat/longs in sql (2012) to find the greatest number of points in a 200m radius. I believe that using the Geography capabilities in sql I can accomplish much of this. To be able to sample the table of points I wanted to create a grid (say of New York - 50m x 50m cells) and move a circle (200m radius) into the center of each square grid cell and then use the buffer function to find what was within the circle. However, I've been searching online and I haven't been able to find a way to create the grid and the central lat/longs.

I am aware of the haversine equation and have used it before (the inverse of this I suppose is what I'm looking for). I would just appreciate some guidance to make sure I don't go down the wrong avenue for too long.

Comment: I don't see what this question has to do with SQL.

Comment: Sorry, I want to be able to do this in sql.

Comment: @J_Garden Did you convince by my answer?

Comment: @AliEshghi thank you for your time. I use sql on a daily basis. I'm looking for the calculation in sql to produce lat/long pairs that are a set number of metres apart, thereby creating a grid represented by a table of lat/longs in sql. This may not be the correct forum for this. Happy to delete the question.

Comment: you don't need to delete it, in my view even question like this can  help others, if you find my answer useful, plz vote it ,TIA

Answer (score 1):

When you are talking about UI You can't handle it in sql.
SQl is a relational database management system, or RDBMS, that supports a wide variety of transaction processing, business intelligence and analytics applications in corporate IT environments. but UI use In information technology, the user interface (UI) is everything designed into an information device with which a person may interact. This can include display screens, keyboards, a mouse and the appearance of a desktop. It is also the way through which a user interacts with an application or a website. The growing dependence of many companies on web applications and mobile applications has led many companies to place increased priority on UI in an effort to improve the user's overall experience .WHEN YOU ARE TALKING A BOUT DESIGN YOU HAVE TO USE UI NOT SQL.
[this link](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-UI-designer-and-UI-developers) can help you to find your solution.